# Opencart - include additional language for content

Tags: fonts, opencart, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I am developing a website (book store) using opencart with English as the store language. I want to add another language ( Malayalam ) to the contents. ie., The store should be in english ( menu, links,etc), but the product description should contain both english and the other language.

Online forums only provides the information to change the store language, not content language.

Please help

Comment: you will need to find and install your language form OpenCart market. https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_category_id=2  also, You will need to add your text in your both language from admin.(menu, etc...)

Comment: All I had to do is to copy paste the contents